# How to reference sub-matrices within a matrix

Tags: java

I have an nxn matrix A where n is a power of 2. The matrix A is divided into 4 equal sized sub-matrices. How can I reference matrices the sub-matrices A11, A12, A21 and A22 in java? I am attempting a divide and conquer matrix multiplication algorithm (Strassen)

```
            A11 | A12
   A -->    ---------
            A21 | A22
```

EDIT: The matrix is stored as integer array: int[][].

Comment: How is your matrix stored? Multidimensional array, or some specialized class?

Comment: With out knowing how it is stored, we can't help you.

Comment: Please see my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358591/getting-reference-of-a-sub-matrix-in-java/4359163

Answer (score 3):

Well, if `i` and `j` are your indices, then A11 is obtained for i = 0..(n/2)-1, j = 0..(n/2)-1.
Then, A12 is for i = 0..(n/2)-1 and j = n/2..n-1 and so on.

To 'reference' them, you just need an "i_min, i_max, j_min, j_max" and instead of running indices from 0 to n-1, run them from min to max.

Comment: How can I pass the reference of the sub-matrix into a method. In C++, I can assign the right address and store it in a pointer to an array. I can pass this pointer to the method.

Comment: Since arrays are passed by reference, you could pass the matrix itself together with the 4 integers defining the boundaries of the element. Or you use some advanced matrix library that allows "slicing".

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of the [Strassen algorithm for matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)

```
import java.io.*;

public class MatrixMultiplication {

    public static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public MatrixMultiplication() throws IOException {
        int n;
        int[][] a, b;

        System.out.print("Enter the number for rows/colums: ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        a = new int[n][n];
        b = new int[n][n];  

        System.out.print("\n\n\nEnter the values for the first matrix:\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the value for cell("+(i+1)+","+(j+1)+"): ");
                a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n\nEnter the values for the second matrix:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the value for cell ("+(i+1)+","+(j+1)+"): ");
                b[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n\nMatrix multiplication using standard method:\n");
        print(multiplyWithStandard(a, b));  

        System.out.print("\n\nMatrix multiplication using Strassen method:\n");
        print(multiplyWithStandard(a, b));  
    }

    public int[][] multiplyWithStandard(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        int n = a.length;
        int[][] c = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                } 
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int[][] multiplyWithStrassen(int [][] A, int [][] B) {
        int n = A.length;
        int [][] result = new int[n][n];

        if (n == 1) {
            result[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0];
        } else if ((n%2 != 0 ) && (n != 1)) {
            int[][] a1, b1, c1;
            int n1 = n+1;
            a1 = new int[n1][n1];
            b1 = new int[n1][n1];
            c1 = new int[n1][n1];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    a1[i][j] = A[i][j];
                    b1[i][j] = B[i][j];
                }
            } 
            c1 = multiplyWithStrassen(a1, b1);   
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    result[i][j] = c1[i][j];
                }
            }   
        } else {
            int [][] A11 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] A12 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] A21 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] A22 = new int[n/2][n/2];

            int [][] B11 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B12 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B21 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B22 = new int[n/2][n/2];

            divideArray(A, A11, 0 , 0);
            divideArray(A, A12, 0 , n/2);
            divideArray(A, A21, n/2, 0);
            divideArray(A, A22, n/2, n/2);

            divideArray(B, B11, 0 , 0);
            divideArray(B, B12, 0 , n/2);
            divideArray(B, B21, n/2, 0);
            divideArray(B, B22, n/2, n/2);

            int [][] M1 = multiplyWithStrassen(add(A11, A22), add(B11, B22));
            int [][] M2 = multiplyWithStrassen(add(A21, A22), B11);
            int [][] M3 = multiplyWithStrassen(A11, subtract(B12, B22));
            int [][] M4 = multiplyWithStrassen(A22, subtract(B21, B11));
            int [][] M5 = multiplyWithStrassen(add(A11, A12), B22);
            int [][] M6 = multiplyWithStrassen(subtract(A21, A11), add(B11, B12));
            int [][] M7 = multiplyWithStrassen(subtract(A12, A22), add(B21, B22));

            int [][] C11 = add(subtract(add(M1, M4), M5), M7);
            int [][] C12 = add(M3, M5);
            int [][] C21 = add(M2, M4);
            int [][] C22 = add(subtract(add(M1, M3), M2), M6);

            copyArray(C11, result, 0 , 0);
            copyArray(C12, result, 0 , n/2);
            copyArray(C21, result, n/2, 0);
            copyArray(C22, result, n/2, n/2);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int[][] add(int [][] A, int [][] B) {
        int n = A.length;  
        int [][] result = new int[n][n]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                result[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
            }   
        return result;
    }

    public int[][] subtract(int [][] A, int [][] B) {
        int n = A.length;
        int [][] result = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                result[i][j] = A[i][j] - B[i][j];
            }  
        }    
        return result;
    }

    private void divideArray(int[][] parent, int[][] child, int iB, int jB) {
        for (int i1 = 0, i2 = iB; i1 < child.length; i1++, i2++) {
            for (int j1 = 0, j2 = jB; j1 < child.length; j1++, j2++) {
                child[i1][j1] = parent[i2][j2];
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyArray(int[][] child, int[][] parent, int iB, int jB) {
        for(int i1 = 0, i2 = iB; i1 < child.length; i1++, i2++) {
            for(int j1 = 0, j2 = jB; j1 < child.length; j1++, j2++) {
                parent[i2][j2] = child[i1][j1];
            }
        }
    }

    public void print(int [][] array) {
        int n = array.length;  

        System.out.println();  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new MatrixMultiplication();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to decide whether to copy the contents of each submatrix each time or to do arithmetic on the addressing. Your questions implies that your submatrices are contiguous rather than split (as in calculating detrminants with minors and cofactors - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html). Since you haven't given an indication of why you wish to do this, what performance hits you have already encountered,  and whether there is recursion to smaller matrices I think that only you can decide on the balance between the simplicity of copying or the complexity of recursive addressing. But I would expect there to be libraries already and I would check http://commons.apache.org/math/.