# Getting reference of a sub-matrix in java

Tags: java, data-structures, matrix

I need to do parallel processing of sub-matrices recursively (original matrix divided into 4 passed into a method). The matrix is stored as a 2D array. I can't copy the elements each time to a new matrix as it turns out to be very expensive. Is there someway to reference the sub-matrices in java?

Perhaps, the question was not clear, I didn't get an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300916/how-to-reference-sub-matrices-within-a-matrix).

Comment: Your question is not clear can you post some more details. Code Perhaps ?

Comment: Your original question was clearer than what you have written here! I suggest you close this and try to clarify the original discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write a wrapper around the `int[][]` data and call it a Matrix class. Then write a method `getSubMatrix(x, y, rows, cols)`. This is a simple Matrix class:

```
static class Matrix {
    int[][] data;
    int x, y, columns, rows;

    public Matrix(int[][] data) {
        this(data, 0, 0, data.length, data[0].length);
    }

    private Matrix(int[][] data, int x, int y, int columns, int rows) {
        this.data = data;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public Matrix getSubMatrix(int x, int y, int columns, int rows) {
        return new Matrix(data, this.x + x , this.y + y, columns, rows);
    }

    public String toString() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = y; i < x + rows; i++) {
            for (int j = x; j < x + columns; j++)
                sb.append(data[i][j]).append(" ");

            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This test program...:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int[][] testData = new int[10][10];

    for (int i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < testData[i].length; j++)
            testData[i][j] = 100 + i + j;

    Matrix full = new Matrix(testData);

    System.out.println("Full test matrix:");
    System.out.println(full);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Part of the matrix:");
    System.out.println(full.getSubMatrix(3, 3, 3, 3));

}
```

...prints:

```
Full test matrix:
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 
102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 
103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 
104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 
105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 
106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 
107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 
108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 
109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 

Part of the matrix:
106 107 108 
107 108 109 
108 109 110
```

Comment: Don't you think that you are passing the entire data array anyway and to string is tailored to just show submatrix?

Answer (score 0):

You already got an answer from Lagerbaer in the question that you reference. You just pass the array (which is a reference to the array in fact), and 4 extra parameters, which are the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some new class that will store `List<List<Integer>>`. In this case you will have probability make some sub lists and pass it other process.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a template class as follows:

```
template <class V, class I = int, class S = FullMatrix<V> >
class Matrix{
private:
    S m_structure; //The matrix structure
    I m_rowstart;//Row start index
    I m_columnstart;//Column start index
}
```

The main constructors would be

```
Matrix();
Matrix(size_t r, size_t c);//r rows and c columns
Matrix(size_t r, size_t c, I rowStart, I columnStart);//rowstart and columnstart are given start indices
Matrix(const Matrix<V, I, S>& source);
```

You would then have functions to return the minimum/max row/column indices of form:

```
I MinRowIndex() const;
```

Next, you have functions to tell the number of rows/columns in the matrix.

```
size_t Rows() const;
```

Then, a function to allow replacement of elements in a row/column by another array of elements

```
void Row(I row, const Array<V, I>& val);//Replace row
```

Then, overload () to allow access to element in a given row and column

```
const V& operator ()(I row, I column) const;//Get Element
V& operator() (I row, I column);
```

Although computational tests may need to be done to check the benefit of this method as compared to maintaining a big matrix and individual start/stop indices of various submatrices (as suggested by Lagerbaer in the other thread) one advantage here is that each submatrix is independent. They can be transposed, moved around, replaced. You probably may need to maintain a higher-level matrix structure in which this Matrix is a sub-structure.

But it does seem to satisfy your question of being able to reference the submatrices independently.