# Algorithm - Searching in 2D matrix

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, hash

I have a larger 2d char grid of `NxN` `(2 <= N <= 800)`. I am given a smaller 2d grid of `KxK` `( 2 <= K <= 100)`. For example, lets N = 3 and K = 2 and followings are the matrices,

Larger:

```
abc
abd
aaa
```

Smaller:

```
bd
aa
```

**Problem 1:**
I have to return if the larger matrix contains the smaller matrix. For example above smaller matrix matched inside larger one.

**Problem 2**: I have to return the staring position mashing part on `NxN` if found. Above example return matched and position = `(1, 1)` #0 based

**My assumption:**

My assumption was to go with hashing. but still if there is any better idea to search efficiently. For example, I can make a hash function which will produce indices for all possible squares from NxN (2x2, 3x3, 4x4, ... , 100x100 as K can be upto 100) for all valid positions

```
(0,0), (0,1), ..., (0, N-K)
(1,0), (1,1), ..., (1, N-K)
. .
. .
(N-K,0), (N-K, 1) .... (N-K, N-K)
```

And then I can keep positions in the associated indices and when a input KxK comes I just run same hash function and see if returned index has a position or not.

Comment: You can probably find something related if you search for image processing algorithms to find a sub-image within an image.

Comment: Bill could plz share if u have any

Comment: Maybe this issue can be solved by generalization [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm) algorithm to 2D (if it's possible).

Comment: Please share details of your hashing approach otherwise we cannot know hoe efficient it already is.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Please see my update

Comment: I don't know how does someone think the question is too broad! isn't it a specific question? why close vote?

Comment: You could create a hash map with roughly 64 million entries max. Then queries can be answered in O(k^2). I think it could work, depends what your goal is. It is not clear if you get the large matrix once and answer several queries or if you get two new matrices each time.

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529278/fastest-way-to-find-a-m-x-n-submatrix-in-m-x-n-matrix and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885147/finding-sub-matrix-of-a-given-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick for this problem is to use a a hash function that you can update in O(1) when you shift one position. This will lower the complexity to O(N^2).

An example of such hash function would be `h = sum(x[i] * 2^i) % some_large_prime_number` . Where `x[i]` is the ascii code of the i-th character. To update you would do

```
h_new = ((h_previous -
          (x[position_to_remove] * 2^k)) * 2 +
          (x[position_to_add] * 2^0
        ) % some_large_prime_number`
```

The hash function is not very strong so you will get some false positives.
To boost the confidence in the match repeat the algorithm with a few different large prime numbers. It can still generate false positives, but they will be rare.

Note: Be careful to pick a prime number that doesn't overflow your integer types. You can apply the '%' operation on intermediate results as well to prevent overflows. Also '%' modulo operation will return a negative number in most languages for a negative input (you need to do the wrap around yourself when you do subtraction).