# Is there a function for selecting a specific part of a 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, random, 2d

So, I have a school project that has 2 players and uses classes for weapons, traps and food and randomly places them on a specific part of the array. I have constructed a 2d array with the corresponding  class type for each one of them, each one respectively called `WeaponAreaLimits`, `FoodAreaLimits` and `TrapAreaLimits`.

```
public class Board{

int[][] weaponAreaLimits = { {-2,2}, {2, 2}, {-2, -2}, {2, -2} };
int[][] foodAreaLimits = { {-3, 3}, {3, 3}, {-3, -3}, {3, -3} };
int[][] trapAreaLimits = { {-4, 4}, {4, 4}, {-4, -4}, {4, -4} }; //These are the specific coordinates that limit the placement of said weapons etc.
....
```

The catch is, weapons can be inside the box made from those points, but, food must be on the points surrounding weapons, not inside the box made from -`3,3 3,3 -3,-3` and `3,-3`.
I constructed a method called `createRandomFood()` that randomly gives properties to `Food` objects. The ones I'm stuck on are the x and y ones, and how to only use those surrounding points and don't put them in a place they shouldn't be. Take a look at what I've written:

```
....
public void createRandomFood(){

    for(int i = 1; i < food.length; i++){
        food[i].setId(i + 1);
        food[i].setX; 
        food[i].setY; 
        food[i].setPoints(rand.nextInt(10) + 1); //Ignore the other setters
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a method or way to eliminate those points?

Comment: I forgot to mention, food is a 1d array that is type Food (Another class)

Comment: Your problem isn't really clear. You have an array that represents your map? I don't understand what your limits arrays are. Does this mean that weapons must be at least 2 slots from any edge, food at least 3, and traps at least 4, with the extra requirement that food must be within one slot of a weapon?

Comment: The instructions manditate that I use a cartesian system for my coordinates, but I have to transform my coordinates to the array blocks (e.g. [0][0] is my upper-left border, but {0, 0} is the center of the table, and if I have a 4x4 board, the upper left corner is (-2, 2)). The weapons must be in the inner blocks of the board, food on the surrounding blocks and traps on the blocks surrounding food.

Comment: So, what you need is a method that lets you set the x,y location of your object randomly with the above constraints and NOT on a cell that already has something?

Comment: Are you dealing with `int` coordinates only or are you allowing points to be `double` e.g. `{-3.2, 2.7}`?

Comment: Exactly. @JosephLarson

Comment: int coordinates only @KarolDowbecki

Comment: Are you allowed to use third-party libraries? Some mathematical libraries provide `Matrix` objects, and may allow you to extract a submatrix. A very quick Google search found this: https://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=SimpleMatrix#Submatrices There's also this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358591/getting-reference-of-a-sub-matrix-in-java

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have to generate a point in outer area (`foodAreaLimits`) that is not part of inner area (`weaponAreaLimits`). The right approach will probably depend on the area shape e.g. what if inner area is a circle while the outer area is a triangle?

You could approach the problem with this algorithm:

1. Generate a random point inside the `foodAreaLimits`
2. If it's outside `weaponAreaLimits` that's good enough.
3. Otherwise randomly pick direction. You are dealing with `int` only so it's simple: west, east, north, south.
4. Change the direction coordinate in the new point until you move outside the `weaponAreaLimits`. You are dealing with `int` so e.g. west would mean move by {-1, 0} so perform `food[i].x--`.

You probably have to think how big are the areas and what is an item distribution. It could be tricky if inner and outer areas are close in size.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming I now understand, first...

Your limits data can be simpler, as long as they represent rectangular limits. You only need minX, maxX, minY, maxY. I would create an object to store those:

```
public class Limits {
    int minX;
    int minY;
    int maxX;
    int maxY;
    public Limits(int x1, y1, x2, y2) {
       minX = x1;
       minY = y1;
       maxX = x2;
       maxY = y2;
    }
}
```

Then your objects become

```
Limits weaponAreaLimits = new Limits(-2, -2, 2, 2);
Limits foodAreaLimits = new Limits(-3, -3, 3, 3);
Limits trapAreaLimits = new Limits(-4, -4, 4, 4);
```

This works because a rectangle can be defined by two diagonal corners. In this case, we're using the lower left and upper right corners. You don't need each vertex.

Now, you need a method like this:

```
public boolean setPoints(Item item, Limits includeRange, Limits excludeRange) {
    // These two variables hold the width & height of the box where things can be
    int width = includeRange.maxX - includeRange.minX + 1;
    int height = includeRange.maxY - includeRange.minY + 1;
    int x;
    int y;

    do {
        x = includeRange.minX + (rand() % width);
        y = includeRange.minY + (rand() % height);
        // At this point, x and y are inside the includeRange.
        // We need to make sure they aren't in the disallowed area
    } while ( (excludeRange == null) ||
      (x >= excludeRange.minX && x <= excludeRange.maxX &&
       y >= excludeRange.minY && y <= excludeRange.maxY) );

    // When the above loop exits, you have an x and y that works.
    item.x = x;
    item.y = y;

    return true;
}
```

I'm not running this through the java compiler, so there might be syntax errors. But basically, we loop, randomly setting x and y inside the outer box until we get a random value that isn't inside the inner box. But we also allow a null inner box so that we can handle weapons with the same method.

Now, what's missing from this -- I'm not checking to make sure this spot isn't occupied by something else. This method should return false if it's unable to work because the entire area is already full. I'll leave that for you. Imagine that you tried to add 50 weapons in an area that can only hold 25.

There are a bunch of important things in here. Aside from the basic structure of the code, there's an understanding of the definition of a rectangle. There's generating random numbers inside that rectangle. And there's the exclusion code.

Hopefully this gives you enough to move forward.