# Getting a submatrix of a 2D matrix in the fastest, most efficient way possible

Tags: java

I realize this question has been asked before, but I just wanted to clarify something. I want to get a submatrix of a 2D matrix represented as an `int[][]`. I saw a [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358591/getting-reference-of-a-sub-matrix-in-java) to create a wrapper class around the `int[][]` data type so that no excess memory is required and you can just get the 2D matrix by reference. My question is, is this different than doing `Array.copyOf()`? My understanding was that `Array.copyOf()` creates a shallow copy of the matrix. I assume this is more memory inefficient because you'd still be creating an array, just one that holds references instead of actual data.

Comment: You're working with primitives, not references so there's no shallow copy involved. The wrapper class shares the array, avoiding any and all copying.

Comment: Then for this wrapper class, I would include a method to index into the main array. Is there a significant difference in calling this method vs. directly indexing into the array if I do it many times?

Comment: Is there a difference between creating one `Matrix` object or creating multiple array objects and copying primitives? Yes, there's a big difference.

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, why are you so keen on copying things? If you want a mutable submatrix, then you'll have to copy. If an immutable submatrix is enough, then you'll want to avoid any copying, and the solution in the link is fine.